# Evaluate a javascript piece of code inside a less function

Tags: javascript, less

Is there any way to evaluate a javascript piece of code inside a less function?

**Example:**

```
contrast((function(){return something}()))
```

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you have to compile it [client-side](http://lesscss.org/#usage).
You need to link

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

and

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to your page.

The [Javascript Evaluation section](http://lesscss.org/#-javascript-evaluation) shows you how to accomplish what you want to do.

Eg.:

```
@var: `"hello".toUpperCase() + '!'`;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer, Yes

For instance this rather pointless code works at http://less2css.org/:

```css
@color: '#ff0000';

.test {
  color: contrast(color(`function(){return @{color}}()`));
}
```

You just need the back tick marks ( ` ) to cause the javascript evaluation in LESS. However, when outputting to a LESS function, you need to be careful that all is as LESS expects. So in my example above, I needed to be sure the function returned a string, which is then converted to a color object in LESS via the `color()` function, which is the type of object that the `contrast()` function is expecting.

Setting `@color` straight to a color value of `#ff0000` without the quotes does not work, because it throws a javascript error. So there are some "picky" aspects to watch for when integrating javascript with LESS, but it is fully possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use ternary operator in a simple expression

```
// add extra width if @miniPlayButton is true
@extraWidth: ~`('@{miniPlayButton}' == 'true' ? 2 : 0)`;

width: 2em + unit(@extraWidth, em);
```

Remember regular Javascript doesn't know about units like `em` so I find it easier (and clearer) to do something like this.

If there is a better reference for similar simple 'recipes' please post it.

I am running this server side with .NET BundleTransformer. Needed to add `javasriptEnabled` or else you get the error message "Syntax
Message: You are using JavaScript, which has been disabled."

```
  <less useNativeMinification="false" ieCompat="true" strictMath="false" strictUnits="false" dumpLineNumbers="None" 
        javascriptEnabled="true" >
    <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
  </less>
```